# When to use “kein” and when “nicht”?

Tags: difference, negation, particle, indefinite-pronoun

> Ich habe keinen Wein.
>   * Ich habe nicht Wein.

Why is the former correct but in the following it’s the other way round?

> Ich verstehe nicht.
>   * Ich verstehe kein.

Comment: You may in particular want to take a look at [this answer](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/3085/2594).

Comment: ask new question more precisely if not duplicated, thanks