# Is my negative indefinite article change correct for wir?

Tags: grammar, negation, grammatical-number

Whilst saying “We don’t understand German” as oppose to “I don’t understand German”, is it correct to change *keine* to *keinen*?

> Ich verstehen keine Deutsche.
>
> Wir verstehen keinen Deutsche.

I mentioned negative indefinite article because I read somewhere that is what *keine* is, but I’m not sure about it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Visit the [help] to learn more about it.

Comment: Both are not correct. In this context "German" is translated as "(das) Deutsch".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence has the main issue that it does not express what you want it to express. If you chose the correct wording, your question would be moot because it can no longer apply. A side-issue is the fact that *keinen* does **not** modify or belong to the verb in any way but is a modifier for the *noun* — in this case, *Deutsche.* It has to agree with the noun it modifies in numerus and genus but *not* with the verb and not necessarily with the subject. Let’s break it down:

## ‘I do not understand German’

Your choice of subject and verb is correct, however German, the language is *das Deutsche* or simply *Deutsch.* Since it is unmodified, so is *kein:*

> Ich verstehe *kein Deutsch.*

You could also choose to word it differently, placing more emphasis on the *not* by saying:

> Ich verstehe Deutsch *nicht.*

*Deutsch,* the language, is uncountable so *kein* before it can **never** be turned into the plural in any way. Also, naturally, the numerus of the object is independent of the numerus of the subject, so changing *ich* to *wir* only modifies the verb:

> *Wir verstehen* kein Deutsch.

## ‘Ich verstehe keine Deutsche’

As stated above, this sentence is correct but it does not mean what you want it to mean. In standard German its meaning is ‘I don’t understand any German (person)’ with the noun being feminine, i.e. female German. Its meaning is not limited to understanding the language but could also mean ‘I can’t follow her way of thinking.’ It can be understood as you being sexist (‘Ich verstehe Deutsche aber keine Deutsche’) so if you are going to use it, do so with extreme caution. Making the subject plural again modifies the *verb* but does not modify the accusative object:

> *Wir verstehen* keine Deutsche.

## *‘Wir verstehen keinen Deutsche’

This sentence, as marked by the asterisk, is not correct. However, you can turn it into a correct one in two different ways:

- Remove the *n* at the end of *keinen:*

  > Wir verstehen keine Deutsche.

  (See above)
- Add an *n* to *Deutsche:*

  > Wir verstehen keinen Deutschen.

This last version has transformed the accusative feminine singular *keine Deutsche* into an accusative masculine singular *keinen Deutschen.* So the sentence’s meaning is essentially ‘I don’t understand a single German.’ (Gendering enthusiasts will only understand it as ‘I don’t understand a single *male* German’, but from a generic and etymological point of view, the masculine genus is a standard genus.) Note again that *verstehen* can also mean *following their way of thinking* etc. Turn this sentence from *wir* to *ich* gives us the following:

> Ich verstehe keinen Deutschen.

## What about not understanding German*s*?

Both these last examples are only correct if you are not speaking of Germans as a group. If you did, you would use the plural form in both English and German. The plural of *ein Deutscher* is especially complicated since it switches between strong and weak inflection: With *kein* or *die,* the noun is inflected weakly to become *keine Deutschen/die Deutschen* whereas lacking an article, it is inflected strongly to become *Deutsche.* Furthermore, in colloquial speech people may speak carelessly and incorrectly use the strong form even though there is a *kein* there. Long story short, the *correct* way to say ‘I don’t understand (any) Germans’ is:

> Ich verstehe keine Deutschen.

Which *may* colloquially be turned into your first example sentence. Again, making the subject plural doesn’t modify the object, so with *wir* it is:

> *Wir verstehen* keine Deutschen.

Again with the caveat that *verstehen* does not only mean *to understand the language.*

Strong inflection would be:

> Ich verstehe Deutsche nicht.

Which is possible but [has a different nuance](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/1103/15318).

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I think I complicated the question by misspelling Deutsch and verstehen by copying from somewhere. I was going to change my question but that would totally mess up the verbose answer, so I wont. Rephrasing the question it would have been more like this: Whilst saying “We don’t understand German” as oppose to “I don’t understand German”, is it correct to change kein to keinen?


Ich verstehe kein Deutsch.

Wir verstehe keinen Deutsch.
Apologies that there are no paragraphs in the comment, Each carriage return saves my comment!

Comment: I gather that I should be changing the verstehe to verstehen rather then kein to keinen when using personal pronoun wir.

Comment: @dirkthedaring That bit is basically answered within the first headline, so yeah. *Kein* belongs to *Deutsch* which is independent of *ich/wir* and *verstehe/verstehen* and thus it is not modified. If you want, I can make that bit even more verbose ;D

Comment: On that note you can say ‘thanks’ by accepting the answer (giving you +2 rep) or, once you hit 15 rep (I think it was) you can also upvote the answer that was helpful to you ^^

Comment: Great. so is 'Wir verstehen kein Deutsch' good speaking? I was a bit thrown by my misspellings.

Comment: @dirkthedaring Yes, it’s perfectly idiomatic and correct. You can make it more polite by adding a *leider:* ‘Wir verstehen leider kein Deutsch.’ But that’s really just finishing touches ;)