# Wann verwendet man "kein" und wann "nicht"?

Tags: negation

Bisher dachte ich, dass "kein" Namen und "nicht" Verben negiert.

Diese Regel habe ich z.B. so angewendet:

> Das ist keine meine Schuld.

Aber, ein hilfreicher Muttersprachler hat mir jetzt gesagt, dass die gültige Form

> Das ist nicht meine Schuld.

ist.

Warum, denn hier negiere ich offensichtlich den Namen?

Comment: [This](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1103/nicht-vs-kein?rq=1) can be a dupe, sorry - although it was asked on English and not on German, if it matters.

Comment: Btw, die Antwort ist: "kein" negiert nur *unbestimmte* Nomen und Pronomen, die bestimmten gehen mit *nicht*, genau wie die Verben (und, ganzer Satz wird mit "nein" negiert).

Comment: »Das ist nicht meine Schuld« negiert meines Erachtens das Verb. Das Substantiv zu negieren wäre »Das ist keine Schuld.« – beachte, dass ich *keine* und *meine* nicht gemeinsam verwenden kann.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Das ist nicht so, wie du annimmst - aber kein Problem...

Die einfache Regel: Kannst du die unten angegebenen Ersetzungen benutzen, ohne den Sinn zu verändern, benutze "kein[e|es|er]". wenn nicht, benutze *nicht*

```
*kein*    nicht ein
*keiner*  nicht einer
*keine*   nicht eine
```

Falls Englisch deine Sprache ist: *kein* translates to *not any*

*kein* negiert Aussagen, die einen unbestimmten Artikel für das Substantiv verwenden, oder wenn es sich um eine nicht bestimmbare/zählbare Menge handelt. Sobald dies nicht der Fall ist, oder ein bestimmter Artikel im Spiel ist, kann man *kein* nicht mehr verwenden.

> Gib mir mal die Milch.
>
> Hier ist keine Milch.

("Milch" ist nicht zählbar)

> Der Junge geht heute in die Schule

negiert:

> Der Junge geht heute nicht in die Schule

Aber:

> Ein Junge geht heute in die Schule

negiert, da unbestimmter Artikel:

> Kein Junge geht heute in die Schule

Comment: Nicht Englisch, aber danke sehr! So habe ich es schon verstanden.

Comment: "Der Junge geht heute in keine Schule." ist auch ein richtiger Satz, hat aber eine andere Bedeutung.

Comment: @Robert "Heute scheint die Sonne und das Gras ist grün" ist auch ein richtiger Satz, hat aber auch eine andere Bedeutung. (???) ;)

Comment: Ich wollte nur sagen, dass es sowohl "geht nicht in die Schule" als auch "in keine Schule" gibt, aber dass die Bedeutung anders ist. "Der Junge ist jahrelang von den Mitschülern gehänselt und verspottet worden. Nach einem Selbstmordversuch wurde er ins Krankenhaus gebracht. Er wurde inzwischen wieder entlassen, aber nach der Erfahrung geht er auf keine Schule mehr."

Comment: @tofro, "Ein Junge geht heute in die Schule nicht" - ist das korrekt?, wann steht "nicht" am Ende?

Comment: @Denis die Formulierung ist nicht verboten, ist aber eher poetisch (z. B. weil sich _nicht_ mit Ende der vorherigen oder nachfolgenden Zeile reimen muss). Die Wortreihenfolge würde man bei _Max und Moritz_ erwarten, nicht in einem normalen Text. _Nicht_ steht am Ende, wenn der Satz kein Objekt hat: "Die Sonne scheint heute nicht."

Comment: @Denis Das ist wahrscheinlich eine eigene Frage wert - Die Positionierung der Verneinung und was sie dann genau verneint, ist eigentlich zu komplex, um in einem Kommentar zu erklären. Und dein Beispielsatz ist zumindestens holprig, wenn nicht falsch.

Comment: @Raketenolli "Nicht am Ende, wenn kein Objekt" Nö: *Nein, ich esse meine Suppe nicht*

Comment: @tofro Tatsache. War eine deutlich zu voreilige Schlussfolgerung. Ich ziehe meine Aussage damit zurück und stimme Dir zu, dass das eine komplett eigene Frage sein sollte. Die in der ein oder anderen Form schon mehrfach gestellt wurde: http://german.stackexchange.com/search?q=where+nicht

Answer (score 3):

"Das ist nicht meine Schuld" negiert nicht die Schuld, sondern das sein (ist). "ist nicht"

Aber "Du hast keine Schuld", also "Du hast nicht eine Schuld"

KEINE bezieht sich auf Substantive/Nomen/Hauptwörter/Gegenstände/Substantive
"eine Schuld" wird negiert zu "keine Schuld"
"ein Haus" wird zu "kein Haus"
Der unbestimmte Artikel "ein/eine/einer" wird zu "kein/keine/keiner"

NICHT wird bei anderen Wortarten verwendet. Zum Beispiel "Das Auto ist nicht grün"
"ist grün" wird negiert zu "ist nicht grün"
"ich mache das" wird zu "ich mache das nicht"
"du gehst zu Fuß" / "du gehst nicht zu Fuß"
"das Auto fährt gut" / "das Auto fährt nicht gut"