# »Ich kann kein/nicht Deutsch sprechen.«

Tags: difference, negation

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen folgenden zwei Sätzen:

> Ich kann kein Deutsch sprechen.
>   Ich kann nicht Deutsch sprechen.

Welche Option ist die richtige? Warum?

Ich habe die anderen Fragen wie ["Nicht" vs "Kein"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1103/nicht-vs-kein) schon gesehen, aber die haben mir nicht geholfen.

Comment: Wenn du "Ich kann nicht Deutsch sprechen" sagtest, könnte es vielleicht in einer Situation passen, wo du unmöglich Deutsch sprechen könntest, weil du sonst dich als Deutschsprachig abgeschleiert oder erkannt würdest.

Comment: Genau an so etwas habe ich auch schon gedacht. Etwa ein Geheimagent, der nicht erkannt werden darf, aber im Ausland auf der Straße von einem alten Schulfreund fröhlich angesprochen wird: A: "Hey, Egon, altes Haus, was machst du denn hier?" - B [flüsternd]: "Pssst! Ich kann hier nicht Deutsch sprechen!"

Comment: "Abgeschleiert" gefällt mir übrigens sehr gut.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann ich leite offenbar an Neologose, ich schaffe immer Worte, die es nicht gibt...

Comment: @Beta Ach, mach dir nichts daraus. Viele Leute haben das heutzutage. Wie ich neulich in der Zeitung las grassiert es sogar in der Duden Redaktion. Schlimme Epidemie das \*scnr\*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beide Sätze sind grammatisch eigentlich richtig. Trotzdem klingen beide - für mein Ohr als Muttersprachler - etwas holprig.

Was würde man in einer typischen Alltagssituation sagen?

> A: Guten Tag, sprechen Sie Ungarisch?
>
> B<sub>1</sub>: Nein, tut mir leid, ich spreche kein Ungarisch.
>
> B<sub>2</sub>: Tut mir leid, Ungarisch spreche ich nicht.
>
> B<sub>3</sub>: Ungarisch? Nö.

Möglicherweise hängt das Unwohlsein, das man mit den Beispielsätzen aus der Eingangsfrage empfindet, auch damit zusammen, dass ein Satz wie "Ich kann kein Deutsch sprechen" (auf Deutsch gesprochen!) in sich widersprüchlich ist. Dies hintangestellt wäre aber die bessere (glattere, üblichere) Formulierung immer noch:

> Ich spreche kein Deutsch.
>
> Ich spreche nicht Deutsch.

Also ohne "kann". Man fragt auch üblicherweise nicht "Kannst du Deutsch sprechen" sondern

> Sprichst du Deutsch?

oder auch, etwas legerer

> Kannst du Deutsch?

"Kannst du Deutsch sprechen" ist offenbar ein bisschen überformuliert (zu sorgfältig, mit zu viel Aufwand formuliert) und fällt deswegen auf als Satz eines ungeübten Sprechers.

Darum auch die kurze Antwort "Ungarisch? Nö." oben von B<sub>3</sub>. Diese wäre in einer Alltagssituation vermutlich von den dreien am häufigsten anzutreffen. Die anderen sind eigentlich auch überformuliert.