# How to negate the following question "Scheint heute die Sonne"?

Tags: question, negation

So if answering yes, I would say

> Ja, die Sonne scheint heute.

but I am not sure on the negative. Can I say

> Nein, die Sonne scheint nicht heute.

or would I say

> Nein, die Sonne scheint heute nicht.

Which one is more suitable?

Comment: *Nein, es ist bewölkt.*

Comment: A simple »Nein«. Is enough. There is no need to repeat this so simple question in the answer. This question is simple enough to assume that everybody still can remember it when they hear the answer.

Comment: @chirlu (－‸ლ) ...

Comment: "Where to put the "nicht" and how does it change the meaning of sentences:   http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/11985/position-of-nicht-and-object/11986#11986 http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5437/position-of-nicht-in-following-contexts

Comment: @Iris Good catch. The scheme is already covered in one of those.

Answer (score 6):

> Nein, die Sonne scheint nicht heute

sagt, dass die Sonne an einem anderen Tag scheint, (aber) nicht heute.

Richtig ist:

> Nein, die Sonne scheint heute nicht.

Mit der Sonne lässt sich der Unterschied schlecht zeigen, weil jeder weiß, dass die Sonne an einem anderen Tag wieder scheinen wird. Daher ein inhaltlich anderes, aber vom Satzbau identisches Beispiel:

> Die Callas singt heute nicht. Sie hat Halsschmerzen.
>
> Die Callas singt nicht heute. Sie singt am Sonntag.

Üblich ist aber ein einfaches **Nein.**

Comment: Und dabei scheint die Sonne zu jeder Zeit, und immer weiter, zumindest für die nächsten 5 Billionen Jahre.

Comment: Ich bin mir nur nicht sicher, ob einem Nicht-Muttersprachler so wirklich klar ist, wo nun der Unterschied zwischen "heute nicht" und "nicht heute" ist. Ich kann übrigens an beide Sätze anhängen, dass sie an einem anderen Tag scheint. "Nein, die Sonne scheint heute nicht, aber morgen wird's sie."

Comment: Ich finde die Formulierung: "Nein, heute scheint die Sonne nicht." ebenfalls ok.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want or need to include the Question text in the Answer:

Then the best Answers would be:

> Nein, die Sonne scheint heute nicht.

To answer about the "actual" weather.

But also answers with a simple No or the addition of any negation of a sunny weather would suite like:

> Nein, es regnet heute.
>
> Nein, heute regnet es.
>
> Nein, es ist bewölkt ...