# How to use "nicht" in questions?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, question, negation

Where should I put *nicht* in question sentences?
For example, would I translate "Why haven't you done?" as "Warum hast nicht du gemacht?", i.e. putting *nicht* after the conjugated verb?

Comment: Basic questions are welcome. Have you seen [this post](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/1101/1691)? There you might find answers.

Comment: Yes, @c.p., I even think it is a duplicate as there is no fundamental difference between questions and other sentences.

Comment: @Sergey: Note that both sentences, the English and the German one, are incomplete; it’s not possible to drop the object (*what* was done?). An ungrammatical sentence structure makes it difficult to reason about the position of the negation. :)

Comment: @chirlu The accepted answer to the other question even addresses the position of "nicht" in questions.